# Html-Entity encoded empty HTML Tag

Tags: mysql, sql, security, xss

Can this combination of characters, alone in a form field, be used for an XSS or SQL attack, if properly "Html-Entity Encoded" right at the beginning of PHP code ?

> <>

Here is a very simple program that shows back the text value in the text field when we submit the form :

```
<?php 

  foreach ($_POST as &$_HTTP_FIELD) {
    $_HTTP_FIELD = htmlentities($_HTTP_FIELD,ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1');
  }
  foreach ($_GET as &$_HTTP_FIELD) {
    $_HTTP_FIELD = htmlentities($_HTTP_FIELD,ENT_QUOTES,'ISO-8859-1');
  }

?>

<html><body>
  <form action="/index2.php" name="abcd" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="texte" value="<? echo $_POST['texte'];?>">
   <input type="submit" name="Soumission" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body></html>
```

I'm sure this does not follow best coding practices but in itself, this code does not seems to be risky if the echo-ed variable is in the "value" field.

But when we try "<>" in the text field, the web hosting firewall will block the request by sending a 403 error.

I'm not specifying the document encoding here for clarity reasons, but in reality the document is made in ISO-8859-1.  So it matches the htmlentities function.

Comment: There is not much informations right now but let's say that my web host won't let my PHP code try to sanitize POST data by itself. An error 403 is thrown even if i loop in all POST variables and delete them.

Comment: Can we see your php code ?

Comment: A variation is to use : $_HTTP_FIELD = ""; in the PHP section, which will juste delete everything... But an error 403 is still thrown if we try "<>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<>` may not work but

```
" onmouseover="alert(1)
```

will probably succeed as this is rendered as

```
<input type="text" name="texte" value="" onmouseover="alert(1)">
```

Comment: As stated in my initial question, my intention is to convert the input to html entities, so the double quotes in your suggestion would be rendered as "&quot;", so totally harmless.  But anyway, if I "forgot" to convert to html entities, "<>" will not do anything harmful as you are saying.  So I consider your answer satisfying. This proves my website host is overestimating the risk about "<>".